# Htaccess - Convert %23 to #

Tags: iphone, .htaccess, linkedin-api

We're having some issues with Linkeding in iPhone. Some shared urls have an `%23.linkedin` path in the url that are causing a 404 error pages.

That happens only in iPhone shared urls.

Some thing like: `https://host.com/2018/05/testing-url/` are being converted to `https://host.com/2018/05/testing-url/%23.linkding_etc`.

We try to convert the `%23` to an `%` to remove the error but no luck.

How can we achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> We try to convert the `%23` to an `%`

I assume you mean `#` (as mentioned in your title), since `%23` is an encoded `#` - a fragment identifier delimiter.

Since fragment identifiers are not passed to the server anyway, you shouldn't be trying to "convert" this. Instead, you should simply be stripping this and everything after it.

For example, using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)# /$1 [R,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the %-decoded URL-path. ie. a literal `#`, not `%23`. The `#` is not a special regex meta character, so you match it like any other normal character in the URL.

The above matches everything *before* `#` and issues a redirect, thus removing the encoded `#` (ie. `%23`) and everything after it.

Note, the above is a temporary (302) redirect. Once you have confirmed that it's working OK then you can change it to a permanent 301 by changing the `R` flag to `R=301`.